# Clicking 'Show More' button on Google Scholar Results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a google scholar page, but I can only get the first twenty results that are shown. I'm trying to use selenium to click 'show more' so that I can get the rest of the results. Here is what I have, however, it isn't working (I have the URL stored in a variable):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="/Applications/chromedriver84")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
element.click()
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Noah, can you please provide the URL?

Comment: Can you increment the number in the URL? https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=20&q=testosterone&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: Here it is: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&hl=en @LuanTorres

Comment: @ZachJohnson No, the URL doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element 'show more' in the page has id = 'gsc_bpf_more', since you know that, you may use Selenium expected_conditions to wait until the button is loaded on the page and then click it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Applications/chromedriver84")
driver.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&hl=en')


try:
    #Wait up to 10s until the element is loaded on the page
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        #Locate element by id
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gsc_bpf_more'))
    )
finally:
    element.click()
```

If you want to check what more Selenium EC can do, check this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thank you Voz bonita!

Comment: Google scholar will block it after several trials. Here is the error "The system can't perform the operation now. Try again later."

Answer (score 2):

You can pass pagination parameters to the request url.

`pagesize` - Parameter defines the number of results to return. (e.g., 20 (default) returns 20 results, 40 returns 40 results, etc.). Maximum number of results to return is 100.

`cstart` - Parameter defines the result offset. It skips the given number of results. It's used for pagination. (e.g., 0 (default) is the first page of results, 20 is the 2nd page of results, 40 is the 3rd page of results, etc.).

So, your URL for the next 100 results should look like this:

> https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&hl=en&cstart=100&pagesize=100

You could also use a third party solution like SerpApi to do this for you. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "hl": "en",
  "author_id": "VjJm3zYAAAAJ",
  "num": "100",
  "start": "100"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"articles": [
  {
    "title": "Comparison of meta-heuristic algorithms for clustering rectangles",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&cstart=100&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VjJm3zYAAAAJ:-f6ydRqryjwC",
    "citation_id": "VjJm3zYAAAAJ:-f6ydRqryjwC",
    "authors": "E Burke, G Kendall",
    "publication": "Computers and Industrial Engineering 37 (1), 383-386, 1999",
    "cited_by": {
      "value": 39,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=17215057896442932540",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=17215057896442932540&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "17215057896442932540"
    },
    "year": "1999"
  },
  {
    "title": "Geometrical insights into the dendritic cell algorithm",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&cstart=100&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=VjJm3zYAAAAJ:kz9GbA2Ns4gC",
    "citation_id": "VjJm3zYAAAAJ:kz9GbA2Ns4gC",
    "authors": "T Stibor, R Oates, G Kendall, JM Garibaldi",
    "publication": "Proceedings of the 11th Annual conference on Genetic and evolutionary …, 2009",
    "cited_by": {
      "value": 38,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=641480971970954670",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=641480971970954670&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "641480971970954670"
    },
    "year": "2009"
  },
  ...
]
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Answer (score 0):

Importing ActionChains you can call .click() function to click on elements at the screen:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VjJm3zYAAAAJ&hl=en')
    more = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gs_btnPD')
    for _ in range(0,5):
        ActionChains(driver).click(more).perform()
        time.sleep(3)
```